# Use images in s3 with SageMaker without .lst files

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, computer-vision, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create (what I thought was) a simple image classification pipeline between s3 and SageMaker.

Images are stored in an s3 bucket with their class labels in their file names currently, e.g.

**My-s3-bucket-dir**

```
cat-1.jpg
dog-1.jpg
cat-2.jpg
..
```

I've been trying to leverage several related example .py scripts, but most seem to be download data sets already in .rec format or containing special manifest or annotation files I don't have.

All I want is to pass the images from s3 to the SageMaker image classification algorithm that's located in the same region, IAM account, etc. I suppose this means I need a `.lst` file

When I try to manually create the `.lst` it doesn't seem to like it and it also takes too long doing manual work to be a good practice.

How can I automatically generate the `.lst` file (or otherwise send the images/classes for training)?

Things I read made it sound like `im2rec.py` was a solution, but I don't see how. The example I'm working with now is

`Image-classification-fulltraining-highlevel.ipynb`

but it seems to download the data as `.rec`,

```
download('http://data.mxnet.io/data/caltech-256/caltech-256-60-train.rec')
download('http://data.mxnet.io/data/caltech-256/caltech-256-60-val.rec')
```

which just skips working with the .jpeg files. I found another that converts them to `.rec` but again it has essentially the `.lst` already as `.json` and just converts it.

I have mostly been working in a Python Jupyter notebook within the AWS console (in my browser) but I have also tried using their GUI.

How can I simply and automatically generate the `.lst` or otherwise get the data/class info into SageMaker without manually creating a `.lst` file?

***Update***

It looks like im2py can't be run against s3. You'd have to completely download everything from all s3 buckets into the notebook's storage...

> Please note that [...] im2rec.py is running locally,
>   therefore cannot take input from the S3 bucket. To generate the list
>   file, you need to download the data and then use the im2rec tool. - AWS SageMaker Team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 options to provide annotated data to the Image Classification algo: (1) packing labels in recordIO files, (2) storing labels in a JSON manifest file ("augmented manifest" option), (3) storing labels in a list file. All options are documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html.

Augmented Manifest and .lst files option are quick to do since they just require you to create an annotation file with a usually quick `for` loop for example. RecordIO requires you to use `im2rec.py` tool, which is a little more work.

Using .lst files is **another option** that is reasonably easy: you just need to create annotation them with a quick for loop, like this:

```
# assuming train_index, train_class, train_pics store the pic index, class and path

with open('train.lst', 'a') as file:
    for index, cl, pic in zip(train_index, train_class, train_pics):
        file.write(str(index) + '\t' + str(cl) + '\t' + pic + '\n')
```

Comment: I guess I knew those things, but nevertheless this does seem to be a valid answers, so I will upvote and select it. I was hoping for something a little more magical, so I may need to change the selected solution if someone submits something more like that. Thanks! Cheers